# Not able to reproduce the result of this paper to test if a system is chaotic or nonchaotic

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, integral-equations

I am trying to reproduce the results of a paper *[A new test for chaos in deterministic systems](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emaslaq/papers/01chaos.pdf)* by *Georg A. Gottwald* and *Ian Melbourne*. This paper talks of a simple 1-0 method to determine whether a dynamical system is chaotic, or not. It's short and simple, so I'll summarise the method below.

The code I wrote is below at the end. My $K$ value is always around 6 or 7 but it should be either near 0 or 1. No matter what I try I do not see where I made a mistake. I did as the paper said. Please help!

---

Assume you have the following dynamical system

[image]

What you need to do is calculate the integrals below, where $\phi(\textbf{x}(s))$ is any observable of the system. The procedure is independent of the choice of $\phi(\textbf{x}(s))$ and the constant $c>0$. The paper chose $\phi(\textbf{x}(t))=x_1(t)+x_2(t)$ and $c=1.7$

[image]

And, finally using $p(t)$ calculate

[image]

According to the paper, $K$ in that limit must be either $0$ (for nonchaotic systems) or $1$ (for chaotic systems). And, that concludes the test.

Now, the dynamical system that the paper uses is the [forced van de Pol oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Pol_oscillator#Forced_Van_der_Pol_oscillator), whose equations of motion could be written as below. Paper chose $a=d=5$, and let $\omega$ vary from $2.462$ to $2.466$ in steps of size $0.00001$. Also, by converting the above two equations for $\theta$ and $p$ to differential equations, we have 4 differential equations which can be numerically solved.

[image]

---

```
x10 = 1; x20 = 1; time = 1000;
 c = 1.7; d = 5; a = 5; \[Omega] = 2.43;
inis = {x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == 1, \[Theta][0] == 0, p[0] == 0};
eqns = {
   x1'[t] == x2[t],
   x2'[t] == -d (x1[t]^2 - 1) x2[t] - x1[t] + a Cos[\[Omega] t],
   \[Theta]'[t] == c + (x1[t] + x2[t]) - (x10 + x20),
   p'[t] == (x1[t] + x2[t]) Cos[\[Theta][t]] - (x10 + x20)
   };
{X1, X2, Th, P} = 
  NDSolveValue[Join[eqns, inis], {x1, x2, \[Theta], p}, {t, 0, time}];
K[t_, T_] := 
 Log[ 1/T NIntegrate[(P[t + \[Tau]] - P[\[Tau]])^2, {\[Tau], 0, T}]]/
 Log[t]
K[Exp[10], Exp[10]]
```

Comment: Criterium `K` they proposed is too tricky, since it needs an integration time  of $T=2\times 10^6$.  It can be compare to $T=10^3$ you have used. I can recommend you to remove `x10, x20` from the code and replace `K` with `k` since `K` is the symbol occupied by the system. Then add `Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", "NonstiffTest" -> False}` to `NDSolve` and try `time= 2 10^6`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I tried adding the method of integration but it's not much of a difference. When I set `time=2 10^6` it takes so long to process that it is practically impossible to plot the type of graph that the paper has plotted of K vs ω. Did you try to run the code with `time= 2 10^6`, was it fast?

Comment: @AlexTrounev it finally produced an output after running for about 7 minutes or a little more but it's practically then same as when I had `time=1000`, that is K is around 6. I don't understand why it would give 6 when the maths I used is exactly what the paper used.

Comment: No it is not fast. Also this method of chaotic and nonchaotic solutions determination looks very strait and not connected with numerical method in use.

Comment: Now use second restriction underlined in the paper that $t<<T$ and use `Log[M[t]+1]/Log[t] ` as they recommended.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I did those as well. It's still the same value around 6. This time I took `time=100` and `T=Exp[20]`.

Comment: Please, see my answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can reproduce one test from the paper using next code

```
x10 = -1.654211168152969`; x20 = 0.6666053281765396`; time = 500000;
c = 1.7; d = 5; a = 5; \[Omega] = 2.463;
inis = {x1[0] == x10, x2[0] == x20, \[Theta][0] == 0, p[0] == 0};
eqns = {x1'[t] == x2[t], 
   x2'[t] == -d (x1[t]^2 - 1) x2[t] - x1[t] + 
     a Cos[\[Omega] t], \[Theta]'[t] == c + (x1[t] + x2[t]), 
   p'[t] == (x1[t] + x2[t]) Cos[\[Theta][t]]};
{X1, X2, Th, P} = 
  NDSolveValue[Join[eqns, inis], {x1, x2, \[Theta], p}, {t, 0, time}, 
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", "NonstiffTest" -> False}];

Kk[t_, T_] := 
 Log[1/T NIntegrate[(P[t + \[Tau]] - P[\[Tau]])^2, {\[Tau], 0, T - t},
       Method -> "QuasiMonteCarlo"] + 1]/Log[t]
```

Now we can prepare lists for small, medium and large `t`:

```
lst = Table[{t, Kk[t, time]}, {t, 1000, 100000, 3000}];
lst1 = Table[{t, Kk[t, time]}, {t, 100, 10000, 300}]
lst2 = Table[{t, Kk[t, time]}, {t, 10, 100, 5}]
```

Visualization
[image: Figure 1]
Therefore at large `t` function `Kk[t]` close to constant about 0.75.

Comment: I didn't notice this before. Why have you changed the limit of integration in $M(t)$ from $\tau=0 \to T$ to $\tau=0 \to T-t$ ? It gives the right answer but I can't see why the change is valid.

Comment: Actually numerical function $P(t)$ is not defined at $t+\tau>time$. When you try to integrate over this limitation Mathematica automatically use extrapolation. It is why you got  answer that `K` is around 6.   Also very important second limitation `t<<T`. If we check picture I have posted, then we realise that small and large `t` not valid for this problem.